# How do I select multiple values ​from a window function?

Tags: postgresql

```
select timezone('utc'::text,t.assigned_at)::DATE as time, 
       organization_id as org_id,  
       row_number () over (partition by organization_id order by t.assigned_at desc ) as rownumber  
from table t
```

```
>               time         org_id rownumber
>                 06.01.2021    13  5
>                 06.01.2021    13  4
>                 06.01.2021    13  3
>                 06.01.2021    13  2
>                 06.01.2021    13  1
>                 06.01.2021    34  3
>                 06.01.2021    34  2
>                 06.01.2021    34  1
```

I need 34: 1, 2, 3.
How to put a search term in a subquery?

```
select * 
from (
  select timezone('utc'::text,t.assigned_at)::DATE as time,
         organization_id as org_id, 
         row_number () over (partition by organization_id order by t.assigned_at desc ) as rownumber  
  from table t
) z
where z.rownumber = ?????
```

Comment: Please add some detail to your question. In its current form it cannot be answered.

Comment: @wildplasser 
thanks for the remark

Comment: `where z.rownumber in (1,2,3)`?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name not that, values dinamic

Comment: That makes it even more confusing. Which part is dynamic? And what is the underlying rule/requirement that makes you choose `org_id = 34`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name динамическая часть - результирующий набор функции окна, может быть 3 значения и 10 значений. org_id = 34 это граница окон. Я пошёл другим путём, не думать как угадать динамический набор, а проставить нужный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need 34: 1, 2, 3. How to put a search term in a subquery?

Just put a WHERE clause into the subquery:

```
select * 
from (
  select timezone('utc'::text,t.assigned_at)::DATE as time
         , organization_id as org_id 
         , row_number ()
             over (partition by organization_id order by t.assigned_at desc )
             as rownumber  
  from table t
  WHERE t.organization_id = 34
) z
where z.rownumber < 4
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dense_rank () over (partition by timezone('utc'::text, t.assigned_at)::date,order by ds.organization_id desc) as dec
where dec=1
```